# Errors when deploying ibm-eventstreams-dev into local environment

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, ibm-cloud-private, ibm-eventstreams

I tried to install ibm-eventstreams-dev v 0.1.2 into my Mac.

After I installed eventstreams into my Mac, there's always several pods that can't run. It includes three kafka pods: es-ibm-es-kafka-sts-0/1/2, es-ibm-es-ui-deploy-69758d9dfd-kc2zx, es-ibm-es-ui-oauth2-client-reg-pgvq6 and there also have a failed job named es-ibm-es-ui-oauth2-client-reg.

You can see the details in the follow images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

So I have two questions about the ibm-event-stream:

- Does ibm-eventstreams-dev only supported on ICP? Can I install it on my local environment without ICP environment?
- How could I solve the ui pods problem in the ibm-eventstreams-dev?
- what's wrong with the kafka pods? what's the status message "CrashLoopBackOff" means?

My environment details:

- kubernetes 1.11.1
- helm : stable 2.10.0
- a cluster have three nodes, each nodes is a virtual macine.

Please help me, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I have two questions about the ibm-event-stream:
>   Does ibm-eventstreams-dev only supported on ICP? Can I install it on my local environment without ICP environment?

Event Streams will only run on IBM Cloud Private (ICP). That's because ICP provides  more than just a Kubernetes environment. For example, authentication and user management for Event Streams is provided by the ICP platform.

That's what the es-ibm-es-ui-oauth2-client-reg job that is failing for you is trying to do - set up the OAuth integration with ICP. And that'll be why it failed for you in Kubernetes on your Mac - because some of the dependencies that Event Streams has will be missing.

> How could I solve the ui pods problem in the ibm-eventstreams-dev?

I'm afraid you won't be able to fix this in just K8S on your Mac - all of the problems that you describe are a result of bits of ICP that Event Streams depends on being missing.

You can get a Community Edition of ICP (at no charge) from https://www.ibm.com/account/reg/us-en/signup?formid=urx-20295 - which would let you give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

ibm-eventstreams-dev will only work in ICP, it can not be installed into your local environment.

Assuming the above is from an ICP instance then I think there are two things to investigate:

- Take a look at the logs for the oauth2-client-reg job, as that should have run successfully to completion as part of the install, using kubectl logs, or the ICP UI.
- CrashLoopBackOff means that a container in the Kafka pod is starting, then crashing, then starting, then crashing, and never managing to start.  Again, take a look at the logs, this time using kubectl logs to see the current logs and kubectl logs --previous to see the previous instance's logs, to get an understanding of why this is.